# No A DNS lookup, so no IP in answer

Tags: dns

I am experimenting Wireshark and have a question. When visiting gezondenlekkerfit.nl I am not getting an IP in the answer of Wireshark. It is only requesting for an AAAA-record.

I only get an Authority RRs back instead of Answer RRs.

What does this mean? Am I looking at it wrong?

Thanks for tips help and education.

Best regards,
Jos

Answer (score 0):

A response with RCODE NOERROR, nothing in the ANSWER section and the relevant SOA record in the AUTHORITY section is a perfectly valid one, meaning that the server claims to be authoritative for the name being queried for, and that the name exists, but that there are no records of the asked-for type for that name.